# About fundamental LinkedList

Tags: linked-list, computer-science

I'm doing a lab report, the assignment is "Write a method called `countWord`. It takes in a `String` and returns the number of times the input `String` is
found in a `LinkedList`."

And this is my code, but when I run it, there is no output.

```
public class LinkedList {
 private Node head; // the 'front' or 'head' node of the linked list
   private int count;

   public LinkedList() {
      head = null;
      count = 0;
   }

   // Method #1
   public void addToFront(String d) {
      Node n = new Node(d, head);
      head = n;
      count++;
   }
```

//rest of code..

```
public int countWord (String d) {
  Node curr = head;
  int index = 0;
  while(curr != null) {
    if(curr.getData().equals(d))
      index++;

    curr = curr.getNext();
  }
}

return index;
}
```

demo class

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[]args){
    LinkedList songs=new LinkedList();
    songs.addToFront("blue");
    songs.addToFront("crooked");
    songs.addToFront("lie");
    songs.addToFront("blue");
    songs.addToFront("sober");
    songs.addToFront("asdf");
    songs.addToFront("blue");
    System.out.println(songs.countWord("blue"));
}
```

}

Comment: Please check the code you sent. You're missing at least one opening curly brace which most likely is in a specific place causing this bug but cannot be seen now. If you remove the first closing brace from this version it should work.

Comment: Sorry , i forgot to type the { here, but I have that brace in eclipse. It still doesnt work .Idk . Is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: What value, if any, gets returned when you feed in a certain string?  My guess is that your linked list has some problem.  Is there any error output?

Comment: Please add it here also. There is no point in putting up code that isn't *exactly* the one you're running, especially when *having* that brace is probably the problem.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. There could be problem with your linked list creation.Try to debug your code from putting break points or simply put some print statements. If not, put your linked list creation code as well here.

Comment: This is rest of my code..